# how to get number of product in each category with nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm newbie nodejs and mongodb. How can i do:

I want to get number of product in each category;

```
cate1(id, name) :
+ product 1(id,name,cate ,created_by)
+ product 2(id,name,cate ,created_by)
+ product 3(id,name,cate ,created_by)
+ product 4(id,name,cate ,created_by)

cate2(id, name) :
+ product 5(id,name,cate ,created_by)
+ product 6(id,name,cate ,created_by)
+ product 7(id,name,cate ,created_by)
+ product 8(id,name,cate ,created_by)
+ product 9(id,name,cate ,created_by)
```

...

When i try to query in nodejs i want to get (id,name, number_of_product).

```
=> cate1 has 4 products
=> cate2 has 5 products
```

How can i do that.

I have a query in mysql:

```
Select cate.id, cate.name, count(*) totalCount 
from cate, product 
where cate.id = 1 and product.cate = 1
```

i could get :

```
[
    {
        id                  : 1,
        name                : cate1, 
        number_of_product   : 4
    },
    {
        id                  : 2,
        name                : cate1, 
        number_of_product   : 5
    },
    {
        id                  : 3,
        name                : cate2, 
        number_of_product   : 2
    }
    ....
]
```

Can someone translate into nodejs and mongodb.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have 2 collections products and categories ?

Comment: yes. @younel if i run query i want to get like that:

Comment: I was thinking that you have one product collection with embedded document represent category

Comment: Thank @younel i have updated my question with mysql query and result. Can you help me

Answer (score 2):

**Mongo shell**

```
db.categories.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: 'products',
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "category_id",
            as: 'products'
        }
    },
    {
        $project:
        {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            number_of_product: { $size: "$products" }
        }
    }
]);
```

**MongoClient**

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db', function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var collection = db.collection('categories');
    collection.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup:
            {
                from: 'products',
                localField: "_id",
                foreignField: "category_id",
                as: 'products'
            }
        },
        {
            $project:
            {
                _id: 1,
                name: 1,
                number_of_product: { $size: "$products" }
            }
        }
    ], function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

**Mongoose**

```
Category.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: 'products',
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "category_id",
            as: 'products'
        }
    },
    {
        $project:
        {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            number_of_product: { $size: "$products" }
        }
    }
]).exec(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
});
```

**Explanation:** the lookup stage will perform a left outer join to products collection, the result is a list of categories with there products grouped in  array, then it comes $project stage, it selects the fields that we need or that we want to calculate from existing fields. the $size operator will calculate the length of products array

Comment: Thank for your post. but i wanna to get form category with the number of Product in them.

Answer (score 2):

*Hi,
I think, this is what you actually want.*

```
Category.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "products",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "category_id",
          as: "products"
        }
      },
      {
        $project:
        {
          _id: 1,
          category: 1,
          totalProducts: {$size: "$products"},
          products: "$products"
        }
      }
    ]
  ).exec(function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    res.end("" + JSON.stringify({data: results}));
  });
```